# Java Spring - dynamic module loading - is OSGi required?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, osgi

I have to develop a program which can be extended by modules at run time using Java Spring Boot.

A module would be implemented as Spring Controller and then installed and loaded at run time.

I found out that this could probably be done using a JavaBean which would then be loaded using GenericApplicationContext as described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-client
.
Unfortunately this documentation also states that dynamic loading at run-time is possible but not officially supported and could lead to errors:

```
Bean metadata and manually supplied singleton instances need to be registered as early as possible, in order for the container to properly reason about them during autowiring and other introspection steps. While overriding existing metadata and existing singleton instances is supported to some degree, the registration of new beans at runtime (concurrently with live access to the factory) is not officially supported and may lead to concurrent access exceptions, inconsistent state in the bean container, or both.
```

However I found some posts where people actually do it.

Another approach would be to use OSGi. And this doc describes it: https://docs.spring.io/spring-osgi/docs/current/reference/html/app-deploy.html but it looks old and so it is maybe outdated.

So does anyone know if OSGi is required to have dynamic module loading at run time for Spring or if Spring does already support this?

Comment: Spring Dynamic Modules has been out of support for many years already and probably doesn't even work anymore with the current versions of Spring. You could try Spring Plugin to have some dynamic loading. But do you really need dynamic loading (and thus probably also unloading) at runtime, instead of with a restart?

Comment: Dynamic loading was the trend when JVM startup time was counted in minutes. Your requirement sounds like an application server... OSGi indeed satisfied demands for highly dynamic JVM processes where ClassLoaders are created in hundreds. This approach is mostly not relevant anymore.
In other words - if you want flat classpath with great architecture, use Spring (Boot/Framework). If you need JavaEE application server, where components are WARs, use Tomcat/Jetty. If you need all other kinds of components, use OSGi runtime like Apache Karaf.